# ionic2 - qqSDK cordova plugin - WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView

Tags: cordova, ionic2

This is what xcode log showing for me when I press sharing button.

> 2017-08-29 09:18:47.754325+0800 MY-AppNAME[432:84271] *** WebKit
>   discarded an uncaught exception in the
>   webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:
>   delegate:  -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170299190

Here is **.ts** file, I did is follow ionic doc.

```
  qqshare(qqmsg){
    this.qq.shareImage(qqmsg.Preview_image1).then(() => {
          console.log('success');
       }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
       });
  }
```

**.html** file

```
  <ion-row>
    <ion-note>share：</ion-note>
    <button ion-fab color="primary" (click)= "qqshare(new)"><ion-icon name="minan-qq"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-row>
```

Comment: If you have found a solution.. Please add as an answer and *not* update in the question.. It needs to follow the Q&A fomat..Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem.

qqSDK is different with SocialSharing plugin, so should write like this

```
qqshare(qqmsg){
    this.qq.shareImage({
      image:qqmsg.Preview_image1
    }).then(() => {
          console.log('成功');
       }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
       });
  }
```